# Android how can i display the output on a spinner if it is on different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, spinner

On my Main activity there is a several buttons, when you click a button , there is an output e.g (rock||paper||scissor). then i will use split to separate it and use intent to go to the next activity. the spinner is on the next activity, how can I display the separate outputs on a spinner?

Comment: Your question is very vague, but I guess this may help: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "a||b||c||d";
String result[] = data.split("\\||");

ArrayList<String> finalDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i < result.length;i++)
{
        System.out.println("At "+i+":"+result[i]);
        finalDataList.add(result[i]);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("resultList", finalDataList);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

now you can take this result array using intent to next activity.

//on activity 2

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
List<String> dataList = bundle.getStringArrayList("resultList");
```

//now use data list in your Activity 2

Comment: thanks,,, but how can i display the result in spinner on the next activity?